# Consume Node.js library in GJS

Tags: node.js, gnome, gnome-3

I have a Gnome Extension where I would like to consume Google APIs. These APIs are available for Node.js.

Is there a way of consuming these in GJS? Or rather have Node.js and GJS work together.

Comment: This extension use internally Nodejs: https://github.com/Rafostar/gnome-shell-extension-cast-to-tv Maybe this can help you to figure out what is needed. Personally i have not idea.

Comment: Hi @abergmeier I also now have this question; just curious if you found an answer and/or any resources.

Comment: Nope. Simply gave up on GJS.